# Computed property not updating on props changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, computed-properties, vue-reactivity

I can't get a computed property to update, when a nested property in a passed prop object is changed.

**this.favourite** is passed via props, but the computed property is not updating when **this.favourite.selectedChoices.second.id** and **this.favourite.selectedChoices.first.id** is changed.

Any ideas of how to make this reactive?

Here's the computed property:

```
isDisabled() {
  const hasMultipleChoices = this.favourite.choices.length
    ? this.favourite.choices[0].value.some(value => value.choices.length) : 
    false;

  if (hasMultipleChoices && !this.favourite.selectedChoices.second.id) {
    return true;
  } else if (this.favourite.choices.length && !this.favourite.selectedChoices.first.id) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: selectedChoices is an array. You're probably modifying its values in ways Vue cannot track: see https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating and https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection

Answer (score 2):

TESTED

In my test.vue

```
props: {
    variant: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
}

const myComputedName = computed(() => {
  return {
    'yellow--warning': props.variant === 'yellow',
    'red--warning': props.variant === 'red',
  }
})
```

test.spec.js

```
    import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
    import test from '@/components/test.vue'
    let wrapper
    
    //default values
    function createConfig(overrides) {
      let variant = ''
      const propsData = { variant }
      return Object.assign({ propsData }, overrides)
    }
    //test
    describe('test.vue Implementation Test', () => {
      let wrapper
    
      // TEARDOWN - run after to each unit test
      afterEach(() => {
        wrapper.destroy()
      })
      it('computed return red if prop variant is red', async (done) => {
        const config = createConfig({ propsData: { variant: 'red' } })
        wrapper = shallowMount(test, config)
        wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
        //checking that my computed has changed, in my case I want to matchanObject
          expect(wrapper.vm.myComputedName).toMatchObject({
            'red--warning': true
          })
          //check what your computed value looks like
          console.log(wrapper.vm.myComputedName)
          done()
        })
      })

//TEST 2 Variant, this time instead red, lets say yellow

      it('computed return yellow if prop variant is red', async (done) => {
        const config = createConfig({ propsData: { variant: 'yellow' } })
        wrapper = shallowMount(test, config)
        wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
        //checking that my computed has changed, in my case I want to matchanObject
          expect(wrapper.vm.myComputedName).toMatchObject({
            'yellow--warning': true
          })
          //check what your computed value looks like
          console.log(wrapper.vm.myComputedName)
          done()
        })
      })
    })
```

for more info, this page helped me.

https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2019/08/26/vue-what-to-unit-test-components/

Comment: where is the call of createLocalVue() ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the computed property didn't update, was because I created the id object of both **this.favourite.selectedChoices.second** and **this.favourite.selectedChoices.first**, after the component was rendered. Declaring the id objects before render was the solution.

Comment: How did you do that exactly, I'm having the same issue

Comment: @Keith Make sure all data you want to watch for changes is declared via props before the component is mounted or via the data function in the component. Basically Vue.js cannot detect changes on data that is declared after the component is mounted in a computed property.