# vue-test-utils doesn't track object props?

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

**Context**

i have a User object which is the data model for a vue.js UserComponent. When the component is mounted the user has undefined fields. Then inside the mounted() method the user is fetched from the server and all its fileds are setted.

**Problem**

So i found that vue-test-utils doesn't redraw component when user's fields changed.

**Note**

On the other hand the same test works good if i change object prop to scalar.

I tried to reset user prop by `wrapper.setProp({user: user})` after its fields was fetchad. Unfortunatelly it is impossible as vue-test-utils preventing to set the same object to prop.

**Demo repo (cloned from official vue-test-utils-getting-started)**

https://github.com/alexey2baranov/vue-test-utils-getting-started

Comment: Show a code where you fill a user from server

Comment: This may be a workaround, to this issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66029922/12237505

Answer (score 0):

When your component have async methods, like fetch user fields on mounted, you have two options when testing:

Option 1: Test with an async function and await for the nextTick
Option 2: Use the package flush-promises

Both options are detailed in the [vuejs test utils documentation](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-async-components.html) with examples.

Also, you can mock axios response with some data for populate your user fields without a real fetch to your backend.

Comment: As i wrote this works only if with scalar types. If you rewrite this examples to objects it brokes

Comment: Can you share the code of your component and your test?

Comment: sure. i cloned official repo and changed its test to object. you can watch it https://github.com/alexey2baranov/vue-test-utils-getting-started